# RadioButton list Binding in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding, enums, radiobuttonlist

I have a radiobuttonList which is binding data from Enum Class and its working correctly in the view.

But my concern is how can I set inital value of radiobutton to `CROCount.ONE`.I have tried to set the initial value in the following way but couldnot get the desired result.

```
public enum CROCount
    {
        ONE = 1,
        TWO = 2
    }
```

**ViewModel is**

```
public class RegistraionVM
{      
    ....  
    public EnumClass.CROCount CROCount { get; set; }       
}
```

**I generated the radio button list as follows.**

```
<div>
    @foreach (var count in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SMS.Models.EnumClass.CROCount)))
    {
         <label style="width:75px">
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RegistrationVenue, (int)count, 
              new { @class = "minimal single" })
              @count.ToString()
         </label>
    }
</div>
```

**Binding performed in the Controller is**

```
public ActionResult Index(int walkInnId)
    {
        try
        {
            var _studentReg = new RegistraionVM
            {
               CROCount=EnumClass.CROCount.ONE                   

            };                               
            return View(_studentReg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use `RadioButtonFor(m => m.RegistrationVenue, count, ...)` - delete the `(int)`

Comment: Tried that mate but not working..

Comment: Works for me - you should be generating `<input type="radio" value="ONE" />` (and `value="TWO"`)

Comment: Sorry, that should be `RadioButtonFor(m => m.CROCount, count, ....)`

Comment: But I cannot navigate to `CROCount` after `m.RegistrationVenue`..

Comment: See my last comment. The duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html but don't affect the binding - but you should use `new { id  "", @class = "minimal single" }` so the `id` attribute is removed

Comment: If your model in the view does not contain a property named `RegistrationVenue` then its just `m => m.CROCount` But you have not shown the model so its unclear what `RegistrationVenue` is

Comment: Sorry mate my mistake :) and its working now.`RegistrationVenue ` was another enumlist.Please post this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding your radio button to property `CROCount` (not `RegistrationVenue`) so your code should be

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CROCount, count, new { id = "", @class = "minimal single" })
```

Note that the 2nd parameter is `count` (not `(int)count`) so that you generate `value="ONE"` and `value="TWO"`. Note also the `new { id = "",` removes the `id` attribute which would otherwise result in duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Comment: If possible kindly look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330545/set-startdate-on-dynamic-datepicker)