# Set startDate on dynamic datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have dynamically created html table using jquery which contains 3rows with input textboxes.The fields of the table are

```
SlNo        Fee          ST       TotalAmt       DueDate
```

On the first row `startDate` of `DueDate` should be the current date.

On the second row `startDate` of `DueDate` should be previously(date of first row) selected date.

On the third row `startDate` of `DueDate` should be previously(date of second row) selected date

**Jquery for dynamically created table**

```
 var $tbody = $("#tblPaymentDetails tbody");
    $($tbody).html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        var slno = parseInt(i + 1);

        var $row = $('<tr/>');
        $row.append(' <td class="slno">' + slno + '</td>');

        $row.append(' <td><input name="StudentReceipt[' + i + '].Fee" type="text" class="form-control"  /></td>');
        $row.append(' <td><input name="StudentReceipt[' + i + '].ST" type="text" class="form-control "  /></td>');
        $row.append(' <td><input name="StudentReceipt[' + i + '].Total" type="text" class="form-control "  /> </td>');
        $row.append(' <td><input id="txtDueDate'+i+'" name="StudentReceipt[' + i + '].DueDate" type="text" class="form-control duedate"  /></td>');

        $tbody.append($row);

    }
```

**Jquery dynamic datepicker**

```
$(document).on('focus', ".dueDate", function () {
    var currentDatepickerId = $(this).attr("id");
    var currMinDate="";
    //For first datepicker
    if (currentDatepickerId == "txtDueDate0") {            
        currMinDate=new Date()
    }
    else {
        //gets the last selected date from the hiddenfield
        var selectedDate = $("#selectedDate").val().split("/");
        currMinDate = new Date(selectedDate[2], selectedDate[0] - 1, selectedDate[1]);
    }     

    $(this).datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: currMinDate           
    }).on("change", function (evt) {
        var currValue = $(this).val();
        //stores the currently selected value to hiddenfield
        $("#selectedDate").val(currValue);
    });

});
```

This is what I have tried.I am getting the desired result on the first attempt.But on resetting the `textbox value` of the `first row` makes the `start date` of the `second row` to the `newDate`

Comment: what have you tryed?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Its unclear what your trying to do with this script and what the logic is. By `startDate` do you mean the minimum date that can be selected?. And is the intention that if you select a date in one datepicker, then the `startDate` of all subsequent rows equals that value (e.g. is you select `1/1/2015` in the 1st row, then you cannot select a date less than `1/1/2015` in the 2nd and 3rd rows?)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment.1)Yes by `startdate` I meant exactly what you said. 2)My intention is for the 1st row `minimnum date` will be currentDate on the 2nd row `minimum date` will be what is selected on the 1st row.On the 3rd row `minimum date` will be what is selected on the 2ndrow.(e.g. if I select `12/20/2015` in the 1st row the minimum date of 2nd row will be `12/20/2015` and if I select `01/01/2016` in the 2nd row, the minimum date of 3rd row will be `01/01/2016` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `changeDate` event of the datepicker to update the `startDate` values in the other datepickers.

Note that I am assuming your using [this datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Start by initializing and setting the default `startDate` value in your script that dynamically creates the table and include a variable to store all datepickers to make selection easier, then handle the `changeDate` event to update all datepickers after this one.

```js
var datepickers; // declare this as global variable

// your function to create the table
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        ....
        $tbody.append($row);
    }
    // store the datepicker elements
    datepickers = $tbody.find('.duedate');
    console.log(datepickers.length); // should return '3'
    // attach the datepicker plugin to each element
    $('.duedate').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: '+0d' // set default to today's date
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        console.log(e.date); // should return the selected date
        var index = datepickers.index($(this)); // should return '1' if you selected the datepicker in the second row
        // loop through all the datepickers after this one
        for(var i = index + 1; i < datepickers.length; i++) {
            // set the startDate based on the date of this one
            datepickers.eq(i).datepicker('setStartDate', e.date);
        }
    });
}
```

And finally, remove your `$(document).on('focus', ".dueDate", function () {` function and the hidden input

Comment: Note one thing I did not take into account is if a date has already been selected in say the last row, and then the user selects a greater date in the first row, then the `startDate` will be greater than the selected date in the last row. Not sure if the plugin automatically adjusts the selected date so its equal to the `startDate` so you may need to add this check as well.

Comment: Okay..sure and thanks for the reminder and will try to check that scenario as well

Comment: Thanks mate its working wonderfully well and solved the above said scenario by adding a small piece of code,so that whenever top row is selected subsequent rows will get cleared. `datepickers.eq(i).datepicker('update','');`

Comment: Sorry, cant help with that one. I assume its to do with Rotativa, and I'm not familiar with it at all.

Comment: Ok.Then what would have been your choice for bulding pdf from html(documentation link will be helpful).

Comment: I have never had to do it so can't make a recommendation. I did try out RazorPDF a few years ago and seems to work OK (refer [example here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/riyazakt/create-pdf-using-razorpdf-in-Asp-Net-mvc/))